# Async Await call with axios returning the result twice

Tags: javascript, async-await, axios, fetch-api

I'm building an online radio app and I'm not sure why the API is been called twice (I'm very new using Promises).

Here's the code:

**Radio.js**
Sorry, I can not show the URL.

```
import axious from 'axios';

export default class Radio {
    constructor(station) {
        this.station = station;
}

async getRadio(){    
    try {
        const res = await axious(`URL HERE/${this.station}`);
        this.result = res.data;
        this.currentTrack = this.result['current-track'];
        this.recentPlayed = this.result['last-played'];
        console.log(this.result);            
        
    } catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}
}
```

**Index.js**

```
'use strict';

import styles from '.././main.scss';
import elements from './views/base';

import Radio from './models/Radio';
import * as radioView from './views/radioView';

const state = {};

/** 
 * RADIO CONTROLLER
 */
  const controlRadio = async () => {   

    state.radio = new Radio(ID STRING HERE);
    try {
        await state.radio.getRadio();
        let imgSRC = state.radio.currentTrack["art"];
        let songTitle = state.radio.currentTrack["title"];
        let songArtist = state.radio.currentTrack["artist"];
        
        radioView.renderPlayerInfo(imgSRC, songTitle, songArtist);
                    

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);         
    }

 }

controlRadio();
```

And here's the result:

[image: The Ouput - console]

Comment: Can we see the content of the 'current-track' object? Does this change between the first and second API call?

Comment: @kaiTaylor I just fixed the issue. I removed the script at the index.html as the **Webpack** was already including the script.  

 `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bundle.js"></script>`

So the script was called twice, silly mistake.
Hey thank you so much for you replay, this is my very first question here at StackOverlflow.